# why perl's if condition is satisfying empty string?

Tags: regular-expression, perl, user-input

The below code works fine, except for the part the STDIN takes an empty value also and goes to first selection `"print "Selected Y \n";"`. If I use `&& $check ne "" ) {` after `/^[Y]?$/i`, the issue with empty STDIN also solves. But the question is why empty value passes there?

```
    my $check = 'NULL';
    while ( $check eq 'NULL' ) {
       print "Do you wish to continue? (Y/N)\n\n";
       print "Enter Selection: ";
       chomp ( $check = <STDIN> );
       if ( $check =~ /^[Y]?$/i ) { 
          print "Selected Y \n";
       }
       elsif ( $check =~ /^[N]$/i ) {
          print "Selected N \n";
       }
       else {
          print "\nInvalid input, please re-enter selection. (Y/N) \n\n";
          $check = 'NULL';
       }
```

I am new to perl, can someone help me understand the behavior?

Comment: `^[Y]?$` matches an optional `Y`, i.e., it matches an empty string or `Y` (due to the `?`). This may be a typo? It is unclear why you use `[Y]` instead of `Y` here.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda. That was it(due to `?`). Could you help me understand the difference between `[Y]` and `Y` ?

Comment: @Kusalananda not a typo I think, that `?` is used to accept Enter as _yes_ answer too.

Comment: @αғsнιη No, `?` is the same as `{0,1}`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I meant `?` in `^[Y]?$` is used to accept the Enter-key as meaning of _yes_ answer when user just hit the Enter key without typing `Y`, so that will `^[Y]?$` match/accept the Enter key which is a empty-string as well. and I assume when using `[Y]` coder's meant was `^[Yy]?$` actually since single `[Y]` is the same as `Y` that you also already pointed that out.

Comment: @αғsнιη I see what you are saying. This appears to be the issue that the user is having. Empty input ("only `Enter`") should not be taken as an affirmative response, which is the whole issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Perl regular expression `/^[Y]?$/i` matches an optional `Y` character case-insensitively.  The `?` affects the `[Y]` in that it allows the `[Y]` to match one or zero characters. This means that the whole regular expression also matches the empty string.

The `[Y]` is identical to just `Y`.  Had you used `[Yy]`, it would have match an upper or lower-case `y` character.  In this case, since you use `/i` to get case-insensitivity, it's enough with `/^Y$/i`.  The same thing goes for the `N` test, use either `/^N$/i` or `/^[Nn]$/`.

For a proper input loop, do something like

```perl
while (1) {
        print 'Do you wish to continue (Y/N): ';
        my $reply = <STDIN>;

        if ($reply =~ /^Y/i) { last }
        if ($reply =~ /^N/i) { print "Bye!\n"; exit }

        print "Sorry, try again\n";
}

print "Continuing...\n"
```

This accepts any response from the user starting with either `n` or `y`, case-insensitively.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the `chomp` in the OP's code was unnecessary as perl's `$` operator matches not only at the end of subject but also before the newline that precedes the end of the subject, if any so, `/^[Y]?$/i` not only matches on "y", "Y" and "", but also "y\n", "Y\n" and "\n". The `chomp` would be useful if you had `print qq(Sorry, "$reply" is not a valid reply, try again.\n)`. In `perl`, you need `\Z` for the equivalent of standard regexp `$`, that is to match *only* at the end of the subject.